# Generate Notification while app is terminated iOS

Tags: iphone, push-notification, crash, ios9, terminate

I am working on an application which will not work if terminated. It has some background tasks. I want to show a push notification if the app is terminated.

Is there any way to generate the push notification while ios app is terminated.

CometChat module implemented in our app, there is a listener for receive the messages, so i want to generate the notification in my app when message receive from CometChat, i know about generate the notification when app is running but i want to generate manually the notification when app is terminated. is there any way to generate then notification manually?

Answer (score 1):

Do it in

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

But be quick. You must finish before applicationWillTerminate returns, and if you take too long, the app will terminate anyway.

Comment: Thanks for reply... Can please explain more ?? i have a little confusion so if u explain than my doubt can be clear..

Answer (score 0):

Generating manual notification when app is terminated is not possible in iOS. You are using CometChat module in your app which uses Parse push notification by default. Parse handles displaying push notification when app is terminated by itself with the help of your bundle identifier of app and p12 certificate which is registered with the Parse. About the push notification generation, you can refer this http://www.intertech.com/Blog/push-notifications-tutorial-for-ios-9/ article.

To know more about the parse push notifications, you can refer https://support.cometchat.com/documentation/php/faq/can-implement-push-notification-app-using-cometchat-sdk/ documentation